# IIS Website failed to fetch dynamically imported module

Tags: iis, windows-server, windows-server-2022

I am trying to get my site to host on an windows 2022 server

When I try to look at my site from the outside with

[http://example.com/{R:1}/page1.html](http://example.com/%7BR:1%7D/page1.html) I get error failed to fetch dynamically imported module:

http://example.com/client/index.7e18705d.js

but when I use

[http://example.com//{R:1}/pageX.html](http://example.com//%7BR:1%7D/pageX.html)

everything works flawlessly.

Expected outcome: Site host normally.

Things tried: Different URL rewrite, tried different server, tried rewriting my index.html file. Outcome happening: Only works flawlessly from any computer or phone browser with the "//" after the domain name. Below is web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <preConditions>
           <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
             <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
           </preCondition>
       </preConditions>
     </outboundRules>
     <rules>
       <rule name="Localhost to Example Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^.*$" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost:5173" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:0}" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you noticed any status code for the error? If yes, I would suggest you use Failed Request Tracing and see how request get processed. It may help to know whether there is any problem with your URL Rewrite rule. Further, check whether the `index.7e18705d.js` file located under client? Is this expected file name `index.7e18705d.js`? Do you have an issue with this specific file? does other file requests works fine?